# Placing a div sidebar next to a centered div

Tags: css, html, css-float, sidebar

I've found a lot of variations to this question within SO, but it seems no matter what I try I can't get this (seemingly very simple!) thing working!

What I'm trying to do is to keep the 'centered' **div** in the center of the viewport and to place the 'sidebar' **div** directly to its right (i.e. *not* right-aligned to the viewport) *without affecting the centering of the 'centered' **div***.

Here's some test code on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6wCyr/13/

Everything I've read seems to imply that the **float** property is exactly what I'm looking for, but the results in the link show that I get weird results wherein the right sidebar is placed *below* the 'centered' **div** rather than beside it. That's what's shown in the link.

I've also seen a solution involving using a negative value for the **right** property, and setting the width of the sidebar exactly, but I couldn't get that one going either.

Hopefully this question is as easy to solve as I think it should be! Just can't seem to find the right set of **div** inside **div** and so forth. Hard to debug these alignment issues!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/DOSBeats/6wCyr/16/

```
.holder {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
}

.centered {
    border: dashed;
    float:left;
    height: 100px;
}

.sidebar {
    border: dotted;
    float:left;
    margin-right:-100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me! It's a bit confusing to me the way I need to set the width and margin of the holder, and set the floats of the centered **and** sidebar etc., but it seems to produce the result I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: It is a little confusing but here's the gist. We first do the basics of setting the holder width so we can center the main box. Then by floating both centered and sidebar left we slide them next to each other...only they stack on top of each other due to the width of the holder element. We then set the margin-right to a negative width which just moves it over where we want. It can be a bit confusing, but you should turn on thing off at a time so you can see what it does.

Answer (score 5):

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/6wCyr/18/)

- I moved `div.sidebar` inside `div.centered`.
- I added `position: relative` to `div.centered`.
- We're using [this technique](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).
- You don't have to declare a fixed width on `div.sidebar`.

**CSS:**

```
div.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: dashed;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative
}

div.sidebar {
    border: dotted;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="centered">
        CENTERED
        <div class="sidebar">
            RIGHT SIDEBAR
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The only downsides of this one versus the approach from @Seth below are that: 1) It involves putting the sidebar div inside the centered div, which seems a bit dirtier to me and 2) The top of the two divs doesn't seem to be aligned properly, whereas they are in the other solution from @Seth. Thanks!

Comment: @aardvarkk: It is really easy to fix that. It's offset by the `border` height. Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/6wCyr/32/ - I should have fixed it in the first place.

Comment: I also really like the way there's no fixed width on the sidebar!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set a width to your holder and center it, the sidebar will float to the edge of the window.

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div id="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder{
  margin:auto;
  width:500px;
}
#sidebar{
  border:dotted;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
}
#centered{
  border:dashed;
  margin-left:110px;
  width:380px;
}
```